# Customizing a barplot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, customization

I want to customize my simple bar plot based on frequency of data. Context as follows:

I have a data set, where x-axis is referred to as `var_change` and y-axis as `var_median` and error-bars as `var_error`. The var_change and var_error are calculated at the bin size of 5-`var_median`. The code and the plot for these variables is shown below:

[image]

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(24,7))
ax = [plt.subplot(181)]
ax[i].barh(np.arange(0+2.5,99+2.5,5), var_change, alpha = 0.6, height = 5, 
           color='none', edgecolor='k', capsize=2.5, lw = 0.8)
ax[i].errorbar(var_change, np.arange(0+2.5,99+2.5,5), xerr = var_error, capsize=3, 
               fmt="r:o", ecolor = "black", alpha = 0.8)
```

I want to independently control both line-width (`lw` in `barh`), and `alpha` in `errorbar`, as well as `color` of individual bars in the bar plot below based on frequency of the data set. The frequency can be calculated using the code below:

```
#df_delta_pos is a data-frame
pos_count = []
for j in np.arange(0,99,5): 
    pos_count.append(df_delta_pos.where((df.var_median> TC_bins[j]) & 
                    (df.var_median<= TC_bins[j+5])).dropna()['var_change'].count())
#Here I would also normalize them if changing 'lw'. Code for normalization can be provided, if needed. 
#For now consider random numbers here.
```

The final plot should look something like below, but also with change in `lw` and `alpha` based on frequency.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide the data to the plot I cannot reproduce the figures.
I try to answer your questions anyways.

1. Controls in `barh`: Taking a look at the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.barh.html) of `barh` you can pass to `color` and `lw` also a list/array which must be of the same length as the data.
2. Controls in `errorbar`: `errorbar` does not allow to specify a list for `alpha`. Your alternative is therefore to loop over each element in `var_change` and plot each element indiviually which then allows you to specify an `alpha` for each point.